# 2 requests in onclick jquery

Tags: javascript

My current button's code is this.

```
<a href="google.com" onClick="correct();"class="button big scrolly"4.6 Inches</a>
```

I have to change href="google.com" into this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(decodeURIComponent( window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('aref=')+5)), '_self');"> </a>
```

What would be the best way to do this without affecting my onClick=correct(); & button class?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to ask us? Why do you have to change the `href` to something else? What does `correct()` do? Usually, the best thing to do is not use `onclick=` attributes at all.

Comment: I don't see jQuery here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, why not do this:

```
<a id="correct" href="#" class="button big scrolly">4.6 Inches</a>
```

And

```
$("#correct").click(function(){
   correct();
   var uri = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('aref=')+5;
   uri = window.location.href.substr(uri);
   uri = decodeURIComponent(uri);
   window.open(uri, '_self');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can pass in multiple methods:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="correct();window.open(decodeURIComponent( window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('aref=')+5)), '_self');"> </a>
```

Or, you can use `window.open()` within the correct method:

```
function correct(){
//your code for correct...
window.open(...)
}
```

And just use `correct()` in onclick.

Comment: + 1 ... Also, create a second function with the `window.open` code that can shorten this up a bit.

Comment: Or you could add `window.open` inside the `correct()` function. This is more like just writing inline JavaScript then passing methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. An element can have both onclick and onmousedown attributes.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="correct();"class="button big scrolly" onmousedown="window.open(decodeURIComponent(   window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('aref=')+5)), '_self');"> </a>
```

Comment: @reneshu you cannot have two onclick attributes...

Comment: Thanks. I meant onclick and onmousedown as I had written above. I changed it but thank you very much for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

you can do that:

```
<a href="google.com" onClick="linker();" class="button big scrolly">4.6 Inches</a>
```

and

```
function linker () {
  correct();
  var url = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('aref=')+5;
  url = window.location.href.substr(url);
  url = decodeURIComponent(url);
  window.open(url, '_self');
}
```